# Program halts trying to read Excel workbook (Apache POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an Excel workbook (`.xlsx`) but the program just halts when initializing a `Workbook`. I'm not sure what's happening as it doesn't give any errors.

When I say halt, I mean the program just pauses. It's still running but I feel like it's stuck, not sure.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader 
{
    private String excelFilePath;
    private FileInputStream inputStream;
    private Workbook workbook;
    private Sheet sheet;

    // Constructors
    public ExcelReader() {
        try {           
            // Get path to excel workbook and put in stream
            excelFilePath = "/home/flow/project/mydata.xlsx";
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

            // Get type of workbook  (Excel 2003 or Excel 2007+)
            workbook = getWorkbook();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Get type of workbook (Excel 2003 or Excel 2007+)
    private Workbook getWorkbook() {    
        Workbook work = null;

        try {
            if(excelFilePath.endsWith("xlsx"))  {
                System.out.println("In firstIf");               // Prints this
                work = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);           // Gets stuck here
                System.out.println("After XSSF");               // Never prints this
            }
            else if(excelFilePath.endsWith("xls"))  {
                work = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            }
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified file is not an Excel file");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return work;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the program ever move on to the next line?

Comment: Dis you try to wait, if so, how much time did you wait?

Comment: I waited over 30 minutes and program did nothing else.

Comment: Try to generate a thread dump (see https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/generating-a-thread-dump-802593021.html for example) and post the output. Also note that the issue might be some other program "locking" the file

Comment: @RC. Sorry, hard to find PID (Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse). Here's the dump: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/20299f9f24e2a2649eae01b450573cb5

Comment: As clearly stated in the docs, [don't use an InputStream if you have a File!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream). Using an InputStream is slower and uses more memory!

Comment: Also your whole `getWorkbook` method would be much much better simply replaced with a call [WorkbookFactory.create(new File(excelPath))](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.File))

Comment: The stacktrace does not show any POI-related code running, so in fact the code terminated in some way, you either swallowed the exception (printSTackTrace() may not be the best option for logging exceptions!) or it finished successfully after all. You likely will need to debug or add more log-output to find out.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Learned a lot from those links and I did fix it. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why the program kept stopping so I downgraded to version 3.9 and got the code to work.
Thanks to [Gagravarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685641/gagravarr), I was able to cut down on the usage of memory by getting rid of the whole `getWorkbook()` method and the `FileInputStream` class.

Change `workbook = getWorkbook()` to this:

```
workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(excelFilePath));
```

It will create the appropriate `XSSFWorkbook` or `HSSFWorkbook`.

Source: [WorkbookFactory.create(...)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.File))

Comment: Apache POI 3.14 should work just fine on Java 6, and there's lots of unit tests and jenkins machines that verify that! What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: I assumed since the above code worked fine with 3.9, something was wrong with 3.14 and Java 1.6. I have no idea what jenkins is, but I'll edit my answer to be more on how I made it work. I tried many test cases and log outputs but couldn't make it work with 3.14.

Comment: Most likely you have a broken or old dependency on your classpath, which newer versions of POI are more sensitive to. Jenkins is a Continuous Integration server, which runs all the unit tests

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with my classpath, so I started a new empty project and still had the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed halt, I mean the program just pauses on the line where XSSFWorkbook is getting initialized.  I found out that a couple of jar files were missing in the class path. In my case the following jars were not in the class path :

```
curvesapi-1.03.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

It is strange that Java run time didn't throw class not found exception. Instead Java runtime was hanging on XSSFWorkbook constructor.

all the jars in POI distribution should be added to class path

```
poi-3.14-20160307.jar
poi-excelant-3.14-20160307.jar
poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
junit-4.12.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
curvesapi-1.03.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```